# ASP.NET Forms authentication not working correctly with load balancer and multiple OS versions

Tags: asp.net, iis, load-balancing

I have behind load balancer 3 machines. 2 of them are Windows 2003 and 1 is Windows 2012.
If I leave in load balancer only machines that are on Windows 2003, everything works fine. As soon as I include Windows 2012, authentication cookie is not propagating correctly to the client.

I've set machine key on all servers to same value and application ID on IIS is set to 1.

Thnx in advance,
Amel

Comment: Encryption differs between .net 2 and 4 and also between x86 and x64. If you mix one of these, it just won't work.

Comment: I've set on Windows 2012 to work as x32 and target framework .net 2. Shouldn't it work same as .net 2 on Windows 2003? Or is it something deeply buried inside OS?

Answer (score 0):

After adding another Windows 2012 machine and shutting down Windows 2003, everything works OK even though it's same .net version, application id and machine/validation keys.